# C++ - Is a pointer required to override return types - inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, return-type

If I have a baseclass, `Attribute`, that has a method named `clone` which returns an `Attribute`, but it's subclass `Direction` gets an error when returning `Direction`.

```
Attribute Attribute::clone() {
    if(this->currentValue) {
        return Attribute(this->type, this->currentValue);
    } else if (!this->param.empty()) {
        return Attribute(this->type, this->param);
    } else {
        return Attribute();
    }
}
```

---

```
Direction Direction::clone() {
    if(this->currentValue) {
        return Direction(this->type, this->currentValue);
    } else if (!this->param.empty()) {
        return Direction(this->type, this->param);
    } else {
        return Direction();
    }
}
```

Although, it works when they both return a pointer to the new `Attribtue`. (ie `return new Attribtue();`, `return new Direction();`). Does the returned value need to be a pointer to an `Attribtue`?

---

**EDIT:** Here are the classes:

```
class Attribute {

public:
std::string param;
std::string type;
float currentValue;

Attribute(std::string type = "absolute", float value = 0);
Attribute(std::string type, std::string param);
~Attribute();
virtual Attribute clone();
};

class Direction : public Attribute{
public:
Direction(std::string type = "absolute", float value = 0);
Direction(std::string type, std::string param);
~Direction();
Direction clone();
};
```

Comment: The return types need to be covariant.

Comment: Could you please provide the method declaration?

Comment: Post your entire code (class declarations). It is strange why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ supports covariant function results for raw pointers and raw references, but not for other types.

And that includes that covariant results are not supported for smart-pointers.

You can however easily work around this language limitation for smart-pointers, e.g.

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual
    auto virtual_clone() const
        -> Base* 
    { return new Base( *this ); }

public:
    auto clone() const
        -> std::unique_ptr<Base>
    { return std::unique_ptr<Base>( virtual_clone() ); }
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
private:
    auto virtual_clone() const
        -> Derived*                // Covariant is OK here. 
        override
    { return new Derived( *this ); }

public:
    auto clone() const
        -> std::unique_ptr<Derived>
    { return std::unique_ptr<Derived>( virtual_clone() ); }
};
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

Note that in this case of smart pointers `unique_ptr<Derived>` is *not* a derived class of `unique_ptr<Base>`, but offers a value conversion to the latter.

---

So, regarding the question title,

> **”** Is a pointer required to override return types - inheritance?

the basic answer is no, you can make things works also with non-pointers, such as smart pointer instances, but it's only *meaningful* for something conceptually pointer-like.

And just to repeat the opening sentence of this answer, at the language level C++ supports covariant function results for raw pointers and raw references, but not for other types.